# Bold and change font color of active nav bar item on click

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make a nav bar where the font changes to bold and color changes to teal when the link is clicked. The problem I'm having is when the links are clicked they change to a blue color and are not bold. About Me stays bolded

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve with the nav bar: https://junye0798.com/

When the item is clicked its set to bold and color teal while the other items set to black and not bold

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.navbar-nav > li").click(function(e) {
    $("ul.navbar-nav > li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  background: #FEFFFF !important;
}

.nav-link {
  color: black;
  padding-right: 0.5 rem;
  padding-left: 0.5 rem;
}

.nav-item.active {
  color: #4ba67f;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
  color: #4ba67f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>My Webpage</title>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
  <div class="container-md">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>ABOUT ME</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>CV</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>PROJECTS</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>GITHUB</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: do you want t keep in teal , even if there is no hovering ?

Comment: What problem do you get from my answer?

Answer (score -1):

you're actually setting the active class to the `li`, but there is a tag inside of it, so it would only color the li tag and not the `a` tag, to solve this add this CSS

```
.nav-item.active , .nav-item.active a {
  color: #4ba67f;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: This didn't seem to change anything

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h0ywoLs3/

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your CSS to this...

```
.navbar{
    background:#FEFFFF !important; 
}
.nav-link{
    padding-right: 0.5 rem;
    padding-left: 0.5 rem;
}
.nav-item > a {
    color:black;
}
.nav-item.active > a{
    color:#4ba67f;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: #4ba67f ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.navbar-nav > li > a").click(function(e) {
    $("ul.navbar-nav > li > a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  background: #FEFFFF !important;
}

.nav-item .nav-link.active {
  color: #4ba67f;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>My Webpage</title>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
  <div class="container-md">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#"><span>ABOUT ME</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>CV</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>PROJECTS</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>GITHUB</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```